# net_adm:ping failure very strange

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

Dears,

I am getting an issue regards to Erlang cluster. After a long time my cluster working, one day, I can't make any connection more to a specific node (e.g.SickNode@X.X.X.X) in the cluster, net_adm:ping(SickNode@X.X.X.X) returns a pang answer. Even using:

**erlang -name abc@X.X.X.X -setcookie MYCOOKIE -remsh SickNode@X.X.X.X**

return a failure result too.

The strange is, **the SickNode@X.X.X.X is working well to other nodes in the cluster**. **The problem just has happened when a new node joining to the cluster and ping to SickNode.**

There isn't any firewall here because all nodes are working well within the cluster. Is there anybody has got this bad situation? Erlang is not stable for cluster using?

PS: I am using Erlang/OTP 20 with Centos 6.8

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Two questions: 1. Can you ping other nodes from your new node (i.e. nodes that are not SickNode@X.X.X.X)? / 2. Can you ping your new node from SickNode@X.X.X.X?

Comment: 1. I can ping from the new node to all other nodes, except the SickNode. A pong result returned to the new node./ 2. From the SickNode, I can't ping to any new node. In the SickNode, when using netstat, I can see old connection (s) keep maintain. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So… I know you said "SickNode@X.X.X.X is working well to other nodes in the cluster." but still… 3. from SickNode, can you ping other nodes (i.e. not new ones, just some other healthy ones)? / 4. from other healthy nodes, can you ping SickNode? / 5. have you checked that the cookie in SickNode is still 'MYCOOKIE'? Maybe it changed after that node was connected to the cluster…

Comment: I can ping pong to healthy nodes from the sick node and vice-versa. Just problem happen with new nodes. I think you are right that, maybe the cookie has been changed. But I wonder, what causes to  the cookie changed? While the sick node has been running quite long time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Not a straight up answer, but a theory and a way to reproduce your issue.
It's complicated because it involves multiple nodes, but let's see if you can follow me.

TL;DR: **SickNode@X.X.X.X** changed its cookie after it was connected to the cluster.

So, this is what I did…
First, on a terminal I started `node1` with cookie `x`…

```
$ erl -name node1 -setcookie x
(node1@my.computer)1>
```

Then, on another terminal I started `node2` with cookie `x`, connected it to `node1` and changed its cookie to `y`…

```
$ erl -name node2 -setcookie x
(node2@my.computer)1> net_adm:ping('node1@my.computer').
pong
(node2@my.computer)2> erlang:set_cookie(node(), 'y').
true
(node2@my.computer)3>
```

Then, in yet another terminal I started `node3`with cookie `x` and pinged `node1` (which resulted in a connection attempt to `node2` as well, as you will see below) and then explicitely tried to connect to `node2`…

```
$ erl -name node3 -setcookie x
(node3@my.computer)1> net_adm:ping('node1@my.computer').
pong
(node3@my.computer)2>
=WARNING REPORT==== 21-Nov-2018::15:09:07 ===
global: 'node3@my.computer' failed to connect to 'node2@my.computer'

=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Nov-2018::15:09:26 ===
** Connection attempt from disallowed node 'node2@my.computer' **
(node3@my.computer)2> net_adm:ping('node2@FERNANDO-BENAVIDES.Conyfero').
pang
```

What happened so far? Well, since `node1`'s cookie was `x` and `node3`'s cookie was `x` as well, they could connect. `node2` was still connected to `node1` but, since the cookie there was `y`, `node3` could not connect to it.

Erlang tries to establish a fully connected mesh of nodes, so when you connect to one of them, it automatically tries to connect you to all the others.

But I wanted to be thorough so I pinged `node2` from `node3` and, as expected I got a `pang`. Also, these messages popped up on `node2`:

```
(node2@my.computer)3>
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Nov-2018::15:09:07 ===
** Connection attempt from disallowed node 'node3@my.computer' **

=WARNING REPORT==== 21-Nov-2018::15:09:07 ===
global: 'node2@my.computer' failed to connect to 'node3@my.computer'
```

And, of course, when I tried to ping `node3` from `node2`…

```
(node2@my.computer)3> net_adm:ping('node3@my.computer').
pang
```

But… if I try to ping `node1`…

```
(node2@my.computer)4> net_adm:ping('node1@my.computer').
pong
```

That's because they're already connected and Erlang only validates the sharing of the cookie on the initial handshake.

Finally, if I try to ping nodes from `node1`, I get the expected results…

```
(node1@my.computer)1> net_adm:ping('node2@my.computer').
pong
(node1@my.computer)2> net_adm:ping('node3@my.computer').
pong
(node1@my.computer)3>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help again! 

Your scenario looks to be same as my issue. But as I commented above, I don't know what is a root cause to make the cookie changed. Could you recommend some reason?

Actually I restarted the sick node then it works well. But this situation is a serious one for me. So for now, I can't check whether or not the cookie was changed.

Comment: Well… the easiest way for a cookie to change is for some process to run `erlang:set_cookie/2` and remember: That thing can be run from _wherever_ (i.e. from _any node_ in the cluster):

`> erlang:set_cookie('SickNode@X.X.X.X', 'the wrong cookie').`

Comment: If someone uses "make" command or "make clean" can cause to the cookie change? I declared cookie in vm.args file, so I don't think anyone changed the cookie by sing that api. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I reproduced the issue again and found that the cookie didn't change as we discussed. Is there any other reason here? After using oberver_cli to inspect the SickNode, new nodes can't join to it.

Comment: Well… maybe observer_cli is the culprit somehow. Does it always happen "After using observer_cli"?

Comment: This is second time after using observer_cli caused to the issue. So I wonder is there anyone had this situation? Should I report this issue to Ericsson? Do you know where is a suitable place to register this issue?

Comment: I don't think Ericsson or the OTP Team had anything to do with observer_cli. It's a third-party lib.
If I were you I would probably start by sending an email to erlang-questions@erlang.org (i.e. this list: http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions). Don't forget to include a link to this SO page.
Then, if you can't find a proper answer there, you may want to report the problem as an issue on the observer_cli github repo: https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli/issues

Comment: Well… a quick look at observer_cli's code resulted in this:

https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli/blob/70948d6086fdc0989418aa6d567c40627c14b165/src/observer_cli.erl#L55

How are you starting observer_cli, @Duke?

Comment: Sorry for some lately response. I eliminated observer out of my project. It made me some risk to use. Anyway when the project size would be bigger,we would not use it because of performance penalty. Thanks for your help!